# create a link with dom and Numbering with "for", But this is messed up

Tags: javascript

This is my code, look at this.

```js
function change(){
  for(a=0;a<1e4;a++){
    let aa = document.createElement('a');
    let bb = document.createTextNode("link " + a)
    let rot = aa.appendChild(bb)
    document.getElementById('div1').appendChild(rot);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
       <input type="submit" onclick="change()" value="Add New Link" class="btn btn-info">
</div>
```

But I want the user to create only one link each time they click and assign a regular number to each link.

But with one click, it creates 9999 links.

Please help me.

Comment: I suspect it creates 10000 links which is how many time the `for` loop iterates. Why are you expecting only one link to be created?

Comment: Side note: It's not the problem, but that code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Declare your variables (`a` for instance).

Comment: What you want to do inside `change()` is get the count of children for `div1`, decrement by 1 (for `input` element) and then use that count for new link's number.

Comment: What do you want to do?? Create one link with nunbering or create 9999 link with numbering? Or do you just want to up the counter each time the userclicks it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create the links all at once, put `a` outside the function and give it an initial value, then use and increment `a` within the function:

```
let a = 0; // Start at 0
function change() {
    if (a < 1e4) {
        let aa = document.createElement("a");
        let bb = document.createTextNode("link " + a)
        let rot = aa.appendChild(bb)
        document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(rot);
        ++a; // Increment `a` for next time
    }
}
```